# Save ImageVector in Android Room database

Tags: android, icons, android-room, converters

I have an application where the user can choose an icon and I want to save that icon. I'm using Compose and for the icons I'm using ImageVector.
I want to store the ImageVector in the room database, so I need to write a converter. Can anyone help me write the converter or if I'm wrong and it's not possible, please give me any information on how to save my icons.

Thanks for any help!

```
@Entity(tableName = "pack_template")
data class PackTemplate(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val icon: ImageVector,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, not sure why you would want to do it though. You can read up on encoding your icon as a Base64 string and then saving it in a field in your room DB. the encoding will increase the size of your icon by 33% and there will be an overhead (encoding/decoding) but that might be ok if your icons are relatively small.

Answer (score 0):

Check this article:

https://medium.com/@nosilverbullet/saving-jetpack-compose-icons-in-room-77eddbe1346c

You only need to save the name of the icon in the database, then you can convert it back to a ImageVector.

To get the name of the icon you can use this code:

```
fun getIconName(icon: ImageVector): String {
    return icon.name.split(".")[1]
}
```

And you can convert it back using this code

```
fun iconByName(name: String): ImageVector {
    val cl = Class.forName("androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.${name}Kt")
    val method = cl.declaredMethods.first()
    return method.invoke(null, Icons.Filled) as ImageVector
}
```